# Is there a free downloadable mini-chess program or 'chess engine'?

Tags: engines, chess-variants, programming

The fascinating miniature chess  or mini-chess ' that is chess on a 6 by 6 board. I know there are tons of decent chess programs but has anyone written a decent chess program for mini-chess. Is there a free downloadable mini-chess program or 'chess engine'?

Comment: Is there any chess program for 6 by 6 chess?

Comment: Chess programs for a 6 by 6 game of chess would be great practice for regular chess.

Answer (score 3):

Zillions of Games isn't free, but it plays Los Alamos chess. ChessV plays 50 chess variants.  I believe Sjaak plays microchess.

ChessV
http://samiam.org/chessv/

Sjaak
http://www.eglebbk.dds.nl/program/chess-index.html

Answer (score 1):

In case you're interested, there is an Android app for that and you can play with the engine:
[Mini Chess](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coderect.chessrect)